# DBML designer file gives an error of duplicates

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a question regarding my dbml file. I've only added one table to this dbml, but for some reason the designer errors out and reports that every single field related to the table in a duplicate, even though they are only declared once. Has anyone else run into this problem? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have another dbml file that add this table to that.if this is true you can transfer one of those in another folder and change it's namespace